# Run-time Error for adding attribute in html meta tag

Tags: asp.net, html, html-parsing

Here is my code:

```
 public partial class Image : System.Web.UI.Page {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
         tag.Attributes.Add("property", "og:type");
         Header.Controls.Add(tag);
     }
}
```

This is my error:

> Server Error in '/Kidzania' Application. Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 18:         HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta(); 
Line 19:         tag.Attributes.Add("property", "og:type"); 
Line 20:         Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

> Source File: d:\Kidzania\Image.aspx.cs    Line: 20
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Image.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:\Kidzania\Image.aspx.cs:20
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +627

i am refer all **stackoverflow**  answer but not solve that problem please any help to assisted me please. thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This how I think it will work.

```
HtmlMeta htmmeta = new HtmlMeta();
htmmeta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:type");
this.Header.Controls.Add(htmmeta);
```

Also you need to make sure that in your mark up header tag has runat server.

```
<head runat="server">
```